# Standard error of regression fit not matching

Tags: r, linear-regression

On this page

http://www.real-statistics.com/multiple-regression/confidence-and-prediction-intervals/

the standard error of the fit for the predicted mean at certain values of X

is given by

```
SE = sqrt(MSE* t(X0) %*% XX %*% X0)
```

When I try to tie the confideince intervals out to the predict() function they are not matching exactley. The confidence intervals are close to what is predicted by predict() but not exact. IS this just a precision issue?

```
set.seed(1234)
x1=1:50
x2=rnorm(50)
y=6+5*x1+3*x2+rnorm(50,0,4)
l=lm(y~x1+x2)
summary(l)
new_data=data.frame(x1=6,x2=.5)
predict(l,newdata=new_data,type="response",interval="confidence")
```

I am tryint to match the confidence intervals here

```
  fit      lwr      upr
1 37.14178 34.90367 39.37989
```

Here is the code from the webpage above:

```
MSE <- sum(l$residuals^2)/(length(x)-2)
est=predict(l,newdata=new_data,type="response",interval="confidence")[1]
X= as.matrix(data.frame(x1=rep(1,length(x1)),x1=x1,x2=x2))
XX= solve(t(X)%*%X)
X0= c(1,6,.5)
SE = sqrt(MSE* t(X0) %*% XX %*% X0)
est - qt(.975, length(x)-2-1)*SE
est + qt(.975, length(x)-2-1)*SE
```

These confidence intervals do not match

```
    [,1]
[1,] 34.92711
> est + qt(.975, length(x)-2-1)*SE
         [,1]
[1,] 39.35645
```

Comment: What is x in "MSE <- sum(l$residuals^2)/(length(x)-2)". It is not defined above that row in your code:

> MSE <- sum(l$residuals^2)/(length(x)-2)
Error: object 'x' not found
>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the first row of the fourth block.

```
MSE <- sum(l$residuals^2)/(length(x)-2)
```

should be

```
MSE <- sum(l$residuals^2)/(length(x1)-3)
```

as you have two variables and an intercept  and as noted in the comment above x isnt defined. It should be really x1.

With this change the code yields: (modifying your last two rows to fit on one):

```
> est +c(-1,1)* qt(.975, length(x1)-3)*SE
[1] 34.90367 39.37989
```

Comment: You could add that in the question it's `qt(.975, length(x)-2-1)` twice when it should be `x1` once again. Upvote, beat me to it.